# How to check table already created or not in SQlite3

Tags: c, linux, sqlite

I am creating a table using `create table ... (sqlite3_open() and sqlite3_exec())` but I don't know how we know that Database file is already created or not.

Answer (score 1):

There are two way to check this:

1) You can check directly while creating a table like this:

```
create table if not exists TableName
```

2) You can check if table already exists before creating the table like this:

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='table_name';
```